# TFS 2017 update2 Store plugin Data

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I wanted to store plugin data in TFS 2017 update 2. I refer this link [TFS Data Storage API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/data-storage) it works with VSTS but when i work with on premises TFS 2017 update 2 it give me an exception

> "TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database:
>   ExtensionData"

How to solve this error. Please help me i stuck in this case. Thanks.

Comment: After some research i found the solution mentioned API is working with VSTS but we have to add **project collection name with APIs** as prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found the solution mentioned API is working with VSTS but we have to add project collection name with APIs as prefix